# Makefile implicit rule with modified target directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here is my current `Makefile`:

```
# DIRECTORY STRUCTURE
# ./libdnx/src/DnxHAL.cpp
# ./libdnx/inc/DnxHAL.h
# ./main.cpp
# 
# REQUIRED COMPILATION STRUCTURE
# ./bin/build/DnxHAL.o
# ./bin/drone_deliver
# 


BUILD_DIR = ./bin/build

LIBDNX_SRCDIR += ./libdnx/src


OBJECTS += ./bin/DnxHAL.o


MAIN = main.cpp
TARGET = ./bin/drone_deliver


$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(MAIN) 
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(LIBRARIES) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(OBJECTS) $(MAIN) -o $(TARGET) 

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(LIBDNX_SRCDIR)/%.cpp 
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARIES) -c -o $@ $<
```

The problem is that when I change the implicit rule to :

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp 
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARIES) -c -o $@ $<
```

it gives error that there is no rule to make `./bin/build/DnxHAL.o` needed by the target. This means that if I have `.cpp` files in another directory, different from `$(LIBDNX_SRCDIR)`, I need to write another rule for them. How can I fix that so that the implicit rule works for all `.cpp` files.

Comment: How do you expect make to find your source files if you don't tell it where they are? Check your entire hard drive until it finds something whose name matches?

Comment: Well, please enlighten me how I can give it the directories where it should search for source files. `VPATH` did not work for some reason

Comment: Your question doesn't mention vpath; it doesn't show your attempt to use it nor does it explain what happened when you tried.

Comment: ...akthough you could also just use one pattern rule per directory.

Comment: I was not entirely sure whether vpath is relevant so I did not mention it. Also my question says that I don't wanna use a pattern rule per directory.

Comment: VPATH is the right answer.